# VSTO - get valid Outlook profile name from registry

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I need to get an Outlook profile from the registry with a name that I can get through VSTO. Everything works until the profile name is written in another language, for example, in Russian. In this case, Outlook writes in registry profile name with undetermined encoding (for example name "тест123" and Outlook writes in registry "[r[u~[q[r123"). Please tell me how to decode the string. Registry path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles<profileName>".

Comment: NameSpace.CurrentProfileName returns valid name but it does not match the registry key name.

Comment: Why do you need to go through the registry?

Comment: To get IMAP user data (IMAP user name, IMAP password, Delivery storeID, IMAP email).

Comment: Yes, but why registry? You can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only, use `IProfAdmin::GetProfileTable`) or Redemption (I am its author, any language) - it exposes `RDOSession.Profiles` collection and a separate ProfMan library.

Comment: Using c# there is only one option - registry.

Comment: You can still try to create headers for the IProfAdmin interface in C# (not for the fainthearted) or you can use Redemption (which can be used from C# just fine).